# CMake wxWidgets DLLs

Tags: dll, cmake, wxwidgets

I'm using CMake. My application uses DLL version of wxWidgets. I'm outputing the apllication's exe file to the specific location within the project tree (e.g. project/bin). What is the best way to automate the process of copying 3rd party shared libraries to executable's directory?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite possible that you could try to automate the creation of bundle using CPack.
Same as described for wxArt2D: [here](http://www.wxart2d.org/moin/WxArt2dInstall)

Also in CMake you can use post-build events like this:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${LIBRARY_NAME} POST_BUILD 
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ARGS -E copy_if_different "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Graphics/WaterEffect/background.jpg" "${WATER_EFFECT_TEXTURE_PATH}/background.jpg"
    )
```